# Warning: This Android Gradle plugin (8.0.0) was tested up to compileSdk = 33

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, java-17

*Android studio Flamingo 2022.2.1* with *Android Gradle plugin 8.0.0* with

```ini
kotlin = "1.8.20"
compileSdk = "33"
compileSdkExtension = "5"
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
targetSdk = "33"
jvmTarget = "17"
kotlinJvmTarget = "17"
```

Why am I getting this message?

> We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 33
>
> This Android Gradle plugin (8.0.0) was tested up to compileSdk = 33.
>
> You are strongly encouraged to update your project to use a newer
> Android Gradle plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 33.
>
> If you are already using the latest version of the Android Gradle plugin,
> you may need to wait until a newer version with support for compileSdk = 33 is available.
>
> To suppress this warning, add/update
> android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33
> to this project's gradle.properties.

Sync, Clean, Rebuild don't help me

Comment: Same issue

"We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34

This Android Gradle plugin (8.0.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 33.

You are strongly encouraged to update your project to use a newer
Android Gradle plugin that has been tested with compileSdk = 34."

Comment: I am on Giraffe and AGP 8.1.0. The problem is still there..

Comment: If you are already using the latest version of the Android Gradle plugin,
**you may need to wait until a newer version with support for `compileSdk = 34` is available**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the max gradle version is linked to the IDE version, so you would have to go with a beta IDE version to make the warning go away. Giraffe and Hedgehog are the two in beta right now. There was an issue in Google's issue tracker that said Giraffe will work.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have 2 options:

- downgrade  `compileSdkVersion 33` and `targetSdkVersion 33`
- keep using with version 34 and hope it will work fine, because it wasn't properly tested, but suggested as compatible

Answer (score 0):

Add `android.suppressUnsupportedCompileSdk=33` to your `gradle.properties` file